# Basic "pass-through" use of FFmpegReader/FFmpegWriter in scikit-video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, scikits

I am starting to use scikit-video and am having trouble writing files. I have reduced the problem to the simplest possible example

```
vid_file = "6710185719062326259_stamp_25pct.mp4"
output_file = "out_temp3.mp4"
reader = skvideo.io.FFmpegReader(vid_file)
writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(output_file)
for frame in reader.nextFrame():
        writer.writeFrame(frame)
writer.close()
```

I'm playing the files in VLC, and the `vid_file` is valid but the output file, though playable, is mostly big green blocks (though I can discern some details from the original video in it).

My goal, or course, is to do "interesting" manipulations of the frame before I write it out, but I need to get the "no modifications" version working correctly first. I'm also going to be using this on large files, so the `vread/vwrite` functions that process an entire file at once are not appropriate.

I'm guessing I need to set the appropriate values in the `outputdict` parameter for the FFmpegWriter, but there are so many that I don't know where to start. I have tried

```
writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(output_file, outputdict={'-crf': '0', '-pix_fmt': 'rgb24'})
```

(`-crf 0` to suppress any compression, `-pixfmt rgb24` as that's what FFmpegReader says it delivers by default, but these don't work either.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Here's the `skvideo.io.ffprobe` video information for the input file.

```
{
    "@index": "0",
    "@codec_name": "h264",
    "@codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
    "@profile": "High",
    "@codec_type": "video",
    "@codec_time_base": "1/30",
    "@codec_tag_string": "avc1",
    "@codec_tag": "0x31637661",
    "@width": "480",
    "@height": "270",
    "@coded_width": "480",
    "@coded_height": "272",
    "@has_b_frames": "2",
    "@pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
    "@level": "21",
    "@chroma_location": "left",
    "@refs": "1",
    "@is_avc": "true",
    "@nal_length_size": "4",
    "@r_frame_rate": "15/1",
    "@avg_frame_rate": "15/1",
    "@time_base": "1/15360",
    "@start_pts": "0",
    "@start_time": "0.000000",
    "@duration_ts": "122880",
    "@duration": "8.000000",
    "@bit_rate": "183806",
    "@bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
    "@nb_frames": "120",
    "disposition": {
        "@default": "1",
        "@dub": "0",
        "@original": "0",
        "@comment": "0",
        "@lyrics": "0",
        "@karaoke": "0",
        "@forced": "0",
        "@hearing_impaired": "0",
        "@visual_impaired": "0",
        "@clean_effects": "0",
        "@attached_pic": "0",
        "@timed_thumbnails": "0"
    },
    "tag": [
        {
            "@key": "language",
            "@value": "und"
        },
        {
            "@key": "handler_name",
            "@value": "VideoHandler"
        }
    ]
}
```

I will mention that when I ffprobe the output file the only differences I see are 1) the timing data is different, which isn't surprising, and 2) the output file has

```
    "@has_b_frames": "0",
    "@pix_fmt": "yuv444p",
```

I'm pretty confident the reader is working okay, because if I write out the data with

```
skimage.io.imsave('x.png', frame,  check_contrast=False)
```

it looks good.

Comment: VLC shows big green blocks? It should be able to handle yuv444p file. Or are you using some other player?

Comment: @llogan - You may have cracked it. I was using VLC to play it, and it was showing big green blocks. But I just dropped the output file into Chrome as a test and it looked fine there! My VLC install might be kind of old, as I'm working on a kind of old machine. If you turn your comment into an answer along the lines of "check if it's a problem with the file or with VLC", I'll retry my code and probably accept it.

Comment: I'm not sure of your requirements, or what FFmpegReader is, so I was hesitant to add an answer. But there is a caveat: most non-FFmpeg based players can't play anything but yuv420p, and some can't handle `-crf 0`. So if you need full compatibility with arbitrary players/browsers you need to use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` instead of `-pix_fmt rgb24` and remove `-crf 0`. Note that libx264 does not support RGB, so that is why it was converted to yuv444p. However, libx264rgb does support RGB, but again, most players can't handle that.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question in case someone has a similar issue. Most of this is from llogan's comments.)

Resolution: scikit-video's `FFmpegWriter()` produced a valid video, but my old version of VLC couldn't play it properly.

Other bits of information that I learned, which might seem obvious but were confusing me:

- In `FFmpegWriter(output_file, outputdict={'-pix_fmt': <FORMAT>}`, FORMAT describes the way that the frames should be encoded before being written to file, not the format of the frames being passed to it.
- `FFmepgReader` seems to default to producing `rgb24`, and `FFmpegWritter` seems to be happy to accept this as input.
- `yuv420p` seems to have been the most common MP4 format  in the past, but these days `yuv444p` seems to be used more, and is the default that `FFmpegWriter` will use.
- Set FORMAT to `yuv420p`  if you want maximal compatibility.
- Trying to play `yuv444p` in programs that don't support it may produce "Video is corrupt" messages, or lots of weird green blocks.

Comment: +1, this helped me solve an issue where default settings `skvideo.io.vwrite` videos saved in ubuntu didn't play anywhere else. I added `outputdict={'-pix_fmt': 'yuv420p'}` and now it works fine!

Comment: @KarolisR - Hey, thanks for leaving your comment. Makes it worth bothering to write-up and post what I discovered.